# Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница

Tags: javascript

Почему в интервал не работает, если в него метод вставить, а если этот метод завернуть в функцию, а эту функцию вставить в интервал - тогда он работает.

```
function Car(x, y, name, country) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        };
    Car.prototype.draw = function () {
        let carHtml = '<img src="images/' + this.name + '.png">';

        this.carElement = $(carHtml);
        
        this.carElement.css ({
            width: "200px",
            position: "absolute",
            left: this.x,
            top: this.y
        });

        $('body').append (this.carElement); 
    };
    Car.prototype.moveDown = function () {
        this.carElement.css({
            left: this.x,
            top: this.y += 5
        });
    };
    let tesla = new Car (30, 50);
    tesla.draw();
```

НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!!! `function int() { var intAnim = setInterval(tesla.moveDown(), 1000); return intAnim; };`

НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!!! `setInterval(tesla.moveDown(), 1000);`

РАБОТАЕТ!  `setInterval(function () {tesla.moveDown()}, 1000);`
ПОЧЕМУ ТАК???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!!! setInterval(tesla.moveDown(), 1000);

Потому что в `setInterval` первым параметром передается `undefined`, который возвращается из `tesla.moveDown()`.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте:

```js
setInterval(tesla.moveDown.bind(tesla), 1000);
```

Подробнее про метод `bind` можно прочитать на [MDS Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в setInterval вы должны передать ссылку на функцию или написать саму функцию внутри. А вы сразу выполняете действие.

```
function move(){
 tesla.moveDown()
}

setInterval(move(),1000) //сразу выполнение функции. setInterval  НЕ сработает
setInterval(move,1000) //ссылка на функцию. setInterval сработает
setInterval(()=> tesla.moveDown(),1000) //функция внутри,  setInterval сработает
```